# I want to delet the OPCACHE on my websites through plugins

Tags: opcache

I want to delet the OPCACHE that makes mthe inodes go out of control on my websites.

Can you suggest a plugin or a simple non-techical way to sort it out please.

I keep getting the large database in MYsql goes to 1.5 Gb rather than 1 Gb allowed for the my sites and keep deleting but comes back immediately. so I do not need a band aid.

As I am not a techincal man a worthy wordpress compatible recommenation is highly appreciated.

Thanking you good guys in advance.

Kindest Regards

I tried to delete manually but it is too complicated and techincal for me to follow.